# How to create a new tab in the Firefox extension and get the elements of the tab

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, dom-events, xul

I want to create a new Firefox extension where the new tab elements can be accessed specially the popup.

```
var win = Components.classes['@mozilla.org/appshell/window-mediator;1']
              .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIWindowMediator)
              .getMostRecentWindow('navigator:browser');
               var a = win.gBrowser.selectedTab;
```

I want to access all the elements which remains open or will open in the new tab in the new tab;
basically I want to know how to access the elements in the new tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean that you want to access the DOM of the page in the tab? If so you can use:

```
var doc = win.getBrowser.contentDocument;
```